# Carbon\Carbon contains abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I updated my composer then I am trying to run my project I can't !!

when I write

```
 php artisan serve
```

I get this error

```
 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Class Carbon\Carbon contains 4 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Carbon\CarbonInterface::__clone, Carbon\CarbonInterface::getLocalMacro, Carbon\CarbonInterface::getMacro, ...)
```

at /Users/macbook/Desktop/egydiet/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php:509

Comment: Please edit the question to: 1) write a title that actually describes the problem, 2) add the commands and error messages as text, not an image and 3) give us a bit more information about what you're trying to do. There's some quality guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have added a down vote as absolutely no clear information was given, a bit of a thumb-suck. After viewing your link however, change your "class MyClassName" to "abstract class MyClassName".

Comment: @El_Vanja I am sorry , I updated my question

Comment: Thank you, I have up voted again. Answer can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371490/how-to-declare-abstract-method-in-non-abstract-class-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am linking to a solution found [Fix: Class abstract methods](https://thisinterestsme.com/class-contains-abstract-methods/).

> When a class contains one or more abstract functions / methods, you must either:
>   Declare the class as an abstract class or
>   Implement the methods in the class that is extending your abstract class.
>   To fix the issue, we can make one simple change. Instead of writing:

```
<?php
class YourClassName{
```

you can write -

```
<?php
abstract class YourClassName{
```

PHP documentation covers this in detail [HERE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Alternatively some good explanations and answers was provided in Stackoverflow [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371490/how-to-declare-abstract-method-in-non-abstract-class-in-php).